# Python `on <something true>:` statement

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a `on <something true>:` statement in python 3?
Like it sets up a listener for something to be True, and does somethig when it is?

Like, can you do something like this:

```
import time
number = 0
on number == 10:
  print("It's 10 time")
  quit()
while True:
  number += 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

Or do i have to do this:

```
import time
number = 0
while True:
  if number == 10:
    print("It's 10 time")
    quit()
  number += 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Or `while number != 10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such statement.
For your example, the easiest thing would just be to to `for _ in range(10)` or `while number != 10`.
I'm assuming your actual use case is more complicated. 
In that case you can build something similar using [Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) and a background thread that just exits the system when the Event is set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I think this will work! I will mark as answer as soon as i can